# How can I display category title inside another category

Tags: category

I would like to display a list of category.
I can display the information inside a category like slug or title.

However, I dont know how to display a category field inside a category.

```
    {% for category in craft.categories.group('handle') %}
       <p> {{category.title}} </p>
       <p> {{category.title}} </p>

    {% endfor %}
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @SethWarburton  A parent category has a category field.  I want to display that category field data by using the parent category .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right you have a category select field inside a category. If you want to grab any field values from a category you can do it the same way as with entries. Code works almost the same.

```
{% for category in craft.categories.group('handle') %}
    <p> {{category.title}} </p>
    <p> {{category.title}} </p>

    {# You can access any field like you normally do inside your category #}
    {{ category.categoryField }}


    {# 
       If you want to access another loop-able
       field inside your category you can just make another loop.
       Like you're looping over entries
    #}
    {% for block in category.categoryFieldName %}
        {{ block.fieldName }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank a lots. that is what i need.